# foreach loop in php missing one interval over last "round" of loop

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have this `foreach` loop:

```
foreach($courses as $course){ //$course is just course name
        $day = $dowMap[$course_day[$course]-1]; //$day = Sun/Mon...
        $date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("next ".$day, strtotime(SEMESTER_START))); //first lectur in semester

        while (strtotime($date) <= strtotime(SEMESTER_END)) {
            if(!array_key_exists($course, $date_arr)){
                $date_arr[$course] = '';
                $date_arr[$course]++;
            }else{
                $date_arr[$course]++;
            }
            $date = date ("Y-m-d", strtotime("+7 day", strtotime($date)));
        }
    }
```

its actually not that complicated,  im creating array - `$date_arr` in which the key is the course name and the value is the number of dates between the beginning and the end of semester were lecture takes place.
so if there 15 Sundays between 2016-01-01 (semester start) and 2016-04-12 (semester end), and course takes place once a week on Sunday then the array will have this part in it:

`["some_course"] => 15`

the all thing works fine except that the last course value always 1 less than it should be.
any idea what am i missing in this loop? or to be more precise why is the last execution over the last course in the `$courses` array is missing?? thx

Comment: If you modify the list of courses - remove half, does it still occur?

Comment: Also, it would really help if you create a 3v4l.org so people could diagnose the problem with data.

Comment: Try adding a count($courses) before your loop to see how many times it's iterating through

Comment: Instead of a loop, why don't you just calculate the number of days between `$date` and `SEMESTER_END`, and divide that by 7?

Comment: thats a good idea ...thx